# Rationale for Mac OS Command-Tab functionality

Tags: mac-os-x

As I recently switched from Linux to Mac, I started wondering why <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> work the way they work.  The first switches between applications, the latter between windows of the same application.

I can think of two UX issues with this design:

1. When switching between windows, it requires cognitive effort to know / remember which one to use.  Especially since a lot of applications are now served as web services, different browser windows can provide very different application functionality.
2. The two key combinations work differently:  Repeatedly pressing (and releasing) <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches back and forth between two applications (even if you have more open), while doing the same with <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> cycles through all windows of that application.  The functionality is the same if you have two windows / applications, but there's no single hotkey to switch back and forth between two browser windows if you have a third browser window open.

Is there some (possibly historic) rationale on why these work as they do, or reasoning why this is a good idea?

(This is not to mention the problem that on many non-US keyboards <kbd>`</kbd> is in a horrible location, and you have to manually configure the shortcut to whatever key is above <kbd>Tab</kbd> to make it at all usable.)

Comment: Actually you can switch back and forth between open windows. Use either *Cmd ⌘* + *<* or *Cmd ⌘* + *>*.

Comment: This exists on Windows too with Alt + Tab swapping to the next app open. In both Windows and Mac if you keep the Alt/Command key held down and press tab you can cycle through the apps only switching to that app when releasing the alt/command key.

Comment: @StephenKeable I know it works that way, that's not the point in the question. The difference between Win/Linux and Mac is that alt-tab switches windows, cmd-tab switches applications (even if the app has multiple windows open).

Comment: @Sampo so it does, didn't notice that nuance on Windows, spend most of my time on a Mac.

Comment: I wrote a blog post further going through the usability problems the Mac OS app switcher has: https://codeforhire.com/2018/03/25/ux-fails-mac-os-app-switcher-and-how-to-fix-it/